# Arm Cortex-M4 LDRD instruction causing hardfault

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, memory-alignment

I notice that in the Cortex-M3 that the `LDRD` (load double word) is [listed in the errata](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka003175/latest), but I'm not finding similar for Cortex-M4, and at any rate, there does not appear to be an interrupt occurring during execution.  I'm working with an M4 microcontroller, and passing data to/from a host.  It's handy to work with the data in the shape the host (same architecture) deals with it - for example, if the host passes an unsigned 16-bit integer, I accept it as a `uint16_t`, even though it is in two byte array `data_in`:

```
uint16_t some_data = *(uint16_t *)data_in;
```

When I try to do this with an unsigned 64-bit integer, however, I get a hardfault on the generated `LDRD` instruction:

```
uint64_t some_data = *(uint64_t *)data_in;
```

generates:

```
9B01        ldr r3, [sp, #4]
330C        adds r3, #12
E9D32300    ldrd r2, r3, [r3, #0]
4902        ldr r1, =SOME_ADDR <some_data>
E9C12306    strd r2, r3, [r1, #24]
```

and I hardfault on `E9D32300    ldrd r2, r3, [r3, #0]`.

So the question is, other than possible portability issues (not a problem here) am I doing something fundamentally wrong by pointing to the location of a uint64_t and trying to read it as a uint64_t?  Either way, has anyone seen an erratum for this instruction reported anywhere?  I'm not finding it in the official docs.

Also, just for completeness, this much less fun code works fine:

```
uint64_t some_data = ((uint64_t)data_in[7] << 8*7) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[6] << 8*6) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[5] << 8*5) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[4] << 8*4) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[3] << 8*3) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[2] << 8*2) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[1] << 8*1) |
                     ((uint64_t)data_in[0] << 8*0);
```

Comment: please dont assume that one core has an errata that it applies to others.  another common mistake is that the errata will apply to a specific core and a specific rev of the core and not necessarly other revs of that same product (cortex-m3.  but certainly no reason to assume that the errata applies to a different product cortex-m4 or a different rev of the same product cortex-m3

Comment: as shown in the answer though any time you get a hardfault on a data access the first thing to look for is alignment.  In this case changing from an ldrh to ldrd (would have been good to try ldr as well) first thought is alignment.  Some cores you can disable the alignment fault and most result in what you would expect, on the older arm7tdmi for example though it is not what you would expect...but repeatable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ARMv7M architecture reference manual, section A3.2.1 "Alignment behavior" it says:

The following data accesses always generate an alignment fault:

- Non halfword-aligned LDREXH and STREXH .
- Non word-aligned LDREX and STREX .
- Non word-aligned LDRD , LDMIA , LDMDB , POP , LDC , VLDR , VLDM , and VPOP .
- Non word-aligned STRD , STMIA , STMDB , PUSH , STC , VSTR , VSTM , and VPUSH .

So unless you know that `data_in` is at-least 32-bit aligned, you can't cast it to `(uint64_t*)` and expect it to work.

Comment: Ah thanks!  So I should probably be using __ALIGN on the incoming data struct (which contains data_in).

Comment: No problem.  If __ALIGN is a macro that expands to something like __attribute__((packed)) then that would force the compiler to do what is in your working example but with less typing for you.

Comment: If this answers your question then please can you accept the answer with the green tick on the left? Thanks.